# error de código

Tags: python, funciones, random, print

```
import random

def saludo():
 return random.randint(0,1)

samurai1 = 0
samurai2 = 0


while samurai1 != 1 or samurai2 != 1:
          samurai1 += saludo()
          samurai2 += saludo()

if(samurai1 == 1 and samurai2 == 0):
          print("El samurai 1 saluda, pero el samurai 2 no")
if(samurai1 == 0 and samurai2 == 1):
          print("El samurai 2 saluda, pero el samurai 1 no")
if(samurai1 == 1 and samurai2 == 1):
          print("Ambos samurai saludan; comienza la pelea")
if(samurai1 == 0 and samurai2 == 0):
          print("Ninguno de los samurai saluda")
```

Hola, no logro que funcione el aleatorio, no sé si me falta una función o está mal alguna parte del código, la idea es lograr quede manera aleatoria, en algunas ocasiones salude uno o el otro, también puede que no salude ninguno o que saluden ambos, la idea es que sea aleatorio gracias

Comment: Solo te falta terminar tu ciclo while con un break coloca break debajo de samurai2 += saludo() y listo, esto es por que tienes que terminar el ciclo si no tu programa entrara en un bucle infinito, espero me haya explicado bien y te sirva, saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que definir las variables `samurai1` y `samurai2`, y definir el ciclo `while` es completamente innecesario

Deberías de añadir la estructura `elif` para que los condicionales se evalúen individualmente, apenas no se cumpla el anterior.

Si deseas acceder al número entero aleatorio que retorna saludar, puedes acceder directamente al valor que retorna la función: `if función() == valor_retornado:`

**Solución:**

Que te parece esta solución?:

```
import random

def saludo():
    return random.randint(0,1)

if(saludo() == 1 and saludo() == 0):
    print("El samurai 1 saluda, pero el samurai 2 no")
if(saludo() == 0 and saludo() == 1):
    print("El samurai 2 saluda, pero el samurai 1 no")
if(saludo() == 1 and saludo() == 1):
    print("Ambos samurai saludan; comienza la pelea")
if(saludo() == 0 and saludo() == 0):
    print("Ninguno de los samurai saluda")
```

**Salidas diferentes con el mismo código!:**

**1:**

```
El samurai 2 saluda, pero el samurai 1 no
```

**2:**

```
Ninguno de los samurai saluda
```

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Answer (score -1):

Hay un problema de lógica en el control del ciclo que es difícil de visualizar, por lo que agregare un `print` para explicarlo:

```
while samurai1 != 1 or samurai2 != 1:
    samurai1 += saludo()
    samurai2 += saludo()
    print(samurai1, samurai2)
```

Obtienes:

```
0 1
0 2
1 2
1 2
1 3
2 4
3 5
4 5
4 5
4 5
```

Nota: son solo los 10 primeros valores, y el resultado es aleatorio.

El `while` se ejecutara mientras **alguno** de los dos samurai sea distinto de uno, lo que también se cumple cuando cualquiera samurai sea 2, 3, 4, ....

Mirando el código, se ve que la intención es salir cuando **alguno** de los dos (o ambos) sea uno.

La condición, correctamente expresada es:

```
while samurai1 != 1 and samurai2 != 1:
```

Expresado de otra manera, el ciclo se ejecutara mientras ambos sean cero, por lo que todo el código se puede reducir, manteniendo el código original tanto como es posible, a:

```
import random

def saludo():
    return random.randint(0,1)

samurai1 = 0
samurai2 = 0

while samurai1 != 1 and samurai2 != 1:
    samurai1 += saludo()
    samurai2 += saludo()

if(samurai1 == 1 and samurai2 == 0):
          print("El samurai 1 saluda, pero el samurai 2 no")
if(samurai1 == 0 and samurai2 == 1):
          print("El samurai 2 saluda, pero el samurai 1 no")
if(samurai1 == 1 and samurai2 == 1):
          print("Ambos samurai saludan; comienza la pelea")
```

La última comparación `if(samurai1 == 0 and samurai2 == 0):` nunca se cumplira, por lo que puedes eliminarla.